# Find equation of tangent line, derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

if $g(x)= xf(x)$, where $f(3)=4$ and $f'(3)=-2$, find an equation of the tangent line to the graph of $g$ at the point where $x=3$

The help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $g'(x) = f(x)+xf'(x)$ by the product rule. Now you have a slope of $g'(3)$ and you can get the y-intercept from what was given to you.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. It made things a lot clearer

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Start by finding $g(3)$ and $g'(3).$ Do you know what either or both of these will tell you about the line?

Comment: g(3) would equal 3*f(x)

Comment: Not quite. Remember, to get $g(3),$ we are assuming that $x=3.$ Not just the first one, but *every* instance of $x.$

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the answers, and this really helped!